# How to set java bean values from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

I want to know how to set values to java variable from jquery.

Html Code:

```
<html>    
  <head>    
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></meta>    
    <title>TEST</title>    
  </head>    
  <script>    
    $(function() {    
      $("#payid").val("1234");    
    });    
  </script>    
  <body>    
    <div>    
      <input type="text" id="payid" value="#{bean.paymentId}">    
    </div>    
  </body>    
</html>
```

Java code

```
public class method(){  

  String paymentId;  

  public void setPaymentId(String paymentId) {  
    this.paymentId = paymentId;  
  }  
  public String getPaymentId() {  
    return paymentId;  
  }  
}
```

But i did not get any value while submitting the form. I am getting null value from bean.

Comment: Are you using Servlet(s) or IoC?

Comment: no I am using only classes

Comment: Metaphorically, I'd say you've put the cart in front of the horse and then you lost the cart (*Poof*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use either ajax call or sockets to communicate.

You need to understand that in classic web applications (without sockets) there are two sides: client and server. Your class is existing on the server side, whereas html/jquery on the client side. And only client can ask server for data, so an event from html page must be 
triggered to push data to server, where you update your POJO (class).

If you could use sockets, you would have 2 way connections, enablish you to update client code from sever and server POJO's from html.

You need to apply an anchange event on monitored field, when it's value changes you need to send a request to your server and update your field.

```
 $.ajax({url:"/my_server/update",data: {value: $("#payid").val()},success:function(result){
        // do some actions on response
  }});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of the value

```
value="#{bean.paymentId}"
```

You should hav written 
    value="${bean.paymentId}"

i.e. replace the # sign with $ sign.